Movie about a voodoo box and doll
From what I remember, this is not really a good movie, low budget and mostly gory-Final Destination-ish teen/high school movie about a (cursed?) voodoo box which contents can make you perform voodoo magic on people.
Like for example on one scene, group of young people started poking needles on a doll and made another person get stab in real time.
Another scene they burned the doll and got another person instantaneously burned for no reason; other voodoo tricks were: breaking limbs, cutting and slashing.
Possible movie details:
Released (less than) 5-7 years ago
Language: English
Country: USA

Sounds like horror movie Needle from 2010.

Ben Rutherford (Michael Dorman), a college student, inherits from his father an 18th-century box, called Le Vaudou Mort. Ben shows the box to his friends, and the very same night the box is stolen. Soon after that, his closest friends start dying in mysterious ways. Le Vaudou Mort is actually a "voodoo" machine designed as a tool for revenge. When the target's photograph is put into the box, a wax doll is created, giving the user power to kill or physically harm the represented person. A killer has started to use the device against Ben’s friends.

Here's the trailer, which includes some of the voodoo doll deaths that you've mentioned [Warning: slightly graphic]:



